# <td> not obeying `width` or `max-width` attributes?

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, cell

I have a table that displays some information regarding the timespan of an event, and that specific info is in a nested table.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Nested Table]

Here is the `<td>` that contains the nested table (PLEASE IGNORE THE RAZOR LOGIC):

```
<td>
    <table class="centered" style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap;">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="left-text" style="max-width: 81px; width: 81px;"><b>All Day?</b></td>
                <td id="AllDay-@item.ExternalID" style="width: 160px;">@(item.AllDay.HasValue && item.AllDay.Value == true ? "Yes" : "No")</td>
            </tr>
            @*Should display StartTime & EndTime if AllDay == true??*@
            <tr id="StartTime-@item.ExternalID" style="display: @(item.AllDay.HasValue && item.AllDay.Value == true ? "none" : "block")">
                <td class="left-text" style="max-width: 81px; width: 81px;"><b>Start Time</b></td>
                <td id="StartTime-@item.ExternalID" style="width: 160px;">@item.StartTime</td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="EndTime-@item.ExternalID" style="display: @(item.AllDay.HasValue && item.AllDay.Value == true ? "none" : "block")">
                <td class="left-text" style="max-width: 81px; width: 81px;"><b>End Time</b></td>
                <td id="EndTime-@item.ExternalID" style="width: 160px;">@item.EndTime</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</td>
```

On the nested table, I have the following style:

```
style="width: 100%; table-layout: fixed; white-space: nowrap;"
```

On each left-hand cell (i.e. "All Day?", "Start Time", "End Time") I have the following style:

```
style="max-width: 81px; width: 81px;"
```

If it's not obvious, none of the nested table's cells are following my style. It's a bit frustrating, since I wasn't even aware that tables could turn into such a ridiculously sloppy mess.

How can I **force** all the table data cells in the nested table to align properly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use `display:table-row;` instead of `display:block;` on your `<tr>` tags.

Alternatively, you could toggle a class with `display:none;` instead of toggling the `display` value.